# Docker - Cassandra with Authentication

Tags: cassandra, docker

I want to setup a Cassandra container with configured authentication on Docker. Currently i'm using the [official Cassandra Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/), but it doesn't seem to provide a option (via the ENV thingies) for enabling Auth Mode.

One possibility would be to setup an own repository, clone from the Cassandra Docker GitHub and modifiy [this file](https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/blob/9062e0160e3a24ec0acb368c69d85153a43bfdb1/3.0/docker-entrypoint.sh) so it also accepts the Auth related options, but this seems a bit to complex for my quite simple task. Does anybody know about a more simple solution or has any hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only option that I can think of (other than making your own version of the image and updating that `docker-entrypoint.sh`, as you suggested) is to provide your own `cassandra.yaml` in a bind mount.  For example:

```
$ docker run -v /path/to/config:/etc/cassandra
```

Where `/path/to/config` is a directory containing your `cassandra.yaml`. Make any adjustments you like to the copy of cassandra.yaml on the host, including your auth changes. To ensure consistency in the configuration, be sure your copy of `cassandra.yaml` matches the version embedded in the docker image.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for! However I already made a pull request for supporting the ENV Variable.

Comment: I tried integrating this into my docker-compose.yml with "  volumes:
    - .:/cassandra/cassandra.yaml:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml", but when starting this it throws: invalid mode for volumes-from: /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml. Any ideas? May this happen since the /etc/cassandra isn't defined as Volume in the cassandra-Dockerfile? Only VOLUME /var/lib/cassandra is declared.

Comment: Your syntax is off. Try just `volumes: - cassandra/cassandra.yml:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml` (no preceding .:)

Comment: This also does not work - I think the problem is that /etc/cassandra is not defined as volume?

Comment: Doesn't have to be in the Dockerfile. Try doing it with a run command (not through docker compose), maybe that will help your troubleshooting

Comment: Ok, somehow this issue does only occur when volume is defined as "file". volumes - ./cassandra:/etc/cassandra seems to work.